# Is it possible to deploy an application with 2 WAR files + 1 EJB.jar file

Tags: jsf, glassfish, ejb-3.0

Here my requirement is to seperate the public portal and admin portal.
Faramework is JSF1.2 , EJB 3.0 and  application server is glassFish 2.x

1. So my question is that can we have 2  WAR files and 1 EJB.jar file
   in single enterprize application?
2. If yes how to access the EJB's
       from both WAR's ?
3. can we deploy and application with both WAR's and EJB?

IDE is Netbeans 7.0 
OS is Windows 7

Any information will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple war files and an EJB jar file packaged in an EAR.

The EJBs will need to have local interfaces, but will be accessible in both web apps.

You probably should not try to deploy the web apps, EJB jar as stand-alone modules and then attempt to deploy an EAR file that contains all of them.  It can be done, but the errors that you are likely to encounter will be a bit confusing.

Comment: Could you some more information on this so that i can proceed with this.

Comment: @user1023877 : what additional info do you think you need?

Comment: information reagarding file structure i.e. in the EAR file j2ee modules are there (one WAR and another one is EJB jar). So my question is how to add another war file to ear and how to configure it?

Comment: @user1023877 : That seems like it is a different question. Some of the details that you will need to add to that question are things like: what IDE you are using? what OS platform are you on? etc.  Remember.. an ear is just a file created using the 'jar' command... that just happens to include files with .war, .rar and .jar suffixes.